# Why are there commas between objects in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object

So we've got some JSON that looks like this:

```
"myBigObj": { 
  "myFirstSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": 42, // in fact!? you could even git rid of these commas too, if all keys are "keys"?
    "attr2": 43 
  }, 
  "mySecondSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": true, 
    "attr2": false 
  }  
}
```

Now, I can see why you've got to have commas between attributes - it delimits the key:value parts, so you can tell where `attr1: 42` begins and ends (as opposed to `attr1:trueattr2:false`).

Which brings me to my question: **Why are there commas between objects**? It seems like the `{}` pairings provide enough information to tell where objects begin, end, and how they're nested... or?

Comment: a consistent structure makes for easier parsing. the parsers would have to be more complicated, if the comma is just present in some cases ...

Comment: @CBroe `{}` is not for arrays but objects. `[]` is used for arrays.

Comment: These appear to be JS object literals, not JSON text. Are you asking about javascript, or about JSON?

Comment: I meant JSON... just being sloppy about it because I'm not real familiar with either. Will update the question.

Comment: ... But the question still stands for JS object literals too, eh? (Except the aside about the attr:value comma-separators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For the sake of the question, I'm going to use the term "JSON" rather than "JS obj. literals". Most (if not all) of what I say should be applicable to JS obj. literals, though.*

Your question is a bit like asking "why do Skittles come in a bag?" For the most part, they just do. There is a little bit of utility of being able to keep the Skittles from melting in your hands, but you could easily have your Skittles without the bag.

Same goes for commas, they only exist to really say "there's something after this, this thing ends here." You **could** make your own object notation (and parser) without them if you really wanted-- they're not required in that sense.

In the case of JSON (and JS obj. literals), commas are used to keep things consistent and readable. JSON wasn't created to be some kind of "optimized data format", it's mostly supposed to be human-readable. That means making things intuitive, like *always* having a comma to separate fields.

Commas (as I've just stated) help make JSON more human-readable. Most English speakers will think of the comma as delimiting the items in a list, which is what they do in JSON: they delimit the items in an object or array.

The only case I can think of where a comma could be useful is, when defining a JS obj. literal, using the comma to separate a regex literal from a field name, when both are on the same line (`regex:/whatever/nextfield:"stuff"`). This could be worked around by either putting the field name in quotes, or creating a `RegExp` object, though.

tl;dr: Commas exist mostly to help JSON be human-readable. They have no real syntactic purpose as one could make their own notation without the commas and it'd work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is an object of objects. But what if you had an object of objects, and arrays, and individual properties? Observe:

```
myBigObj: { 
  "myFirstSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": 42, 
    "attr2": 43 
  }, 
  "mySecondSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": true, 
    "attr2": false 
  },
  "myFirstArray": [1,2,3],
  "myString": "someString"
}
```

In this case, the `{}` pairings are not enough to tell where the `myBigObj` ends. By the way, valid JSON requires the property names to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*not enough to tell where the myBigObj ends*", can you elaborate?

Comment: It's a response to this statement in the original post: "It seems like the `{}` pairings provide enough information to tell where objects begin, end, and how they're nested..."

Comment: But they do? You *could* omit the commata (or make them optional), and it would still be a non-ambiguous grammar.

Comment: As long as `:` separate `key:value` pairs, and as long as value types were notated (`[arrays]`, '"strings"'...), I think you could still tell where `myBigObj` starts and ends. Or?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON object.

You can use an online validator to confirm:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Indeed, it is not valid [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ...

Answer (score 0):

The comma between attributes in JSON comes from same comma on JavaScript literal Objects, you can check them out on this website (http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/) where says "A JavaScript object literal is a comma-separated list of name-value pairs wrapped in curly braces. Object literals encapsulate data, enclosing it in a tidy package. This minimizes the use of global variables which can cause problems when combining code."

In your case you are using a json like:

```
"myBigObj": { 
  "myFirstSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": 42, 
    "attr2": 43 
  }, 
  "mySecondSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": true, 
    "attr2": false 
  }  
}
```

where myBigObj has two attributes, myFirstSmallerObj and mySecondSmallerObj, each attribute is another object but if not, the comma still there like this:

```
"myBigObj": { 
  "myFirstSmallerObj": [42, 43], 
  "mySecondSmallerObj": { 
    "attr1": true, 
    "attr2": false 
  }  
}
```

more refs: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp